# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'company_name' (T_STRING)

Tags: php

what am i gonna put inside the for loop to connect it to the database

```
<?php
try {
require ("db.php");
 $sql = ("select company_name, company_logo from company");
mysql_query($sql);

for () {
    print '<a href="systemlogin2.php">$row['company_name']</h2>';
    print '<p><img border="0" src="$row['company_logo']" width="230" height="198"></p>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Please do not avoid reading the documentation/manuals.

Comment: Your problem is a simple typographical error and is off-topic here

Answer (score 0):

Hello PHP tries to execute "company_name"

```
print '<h2><a href="systemlogin2.php">'.$row["company_name"].'</a></h2>';
```

Should be working!

Comment: Oh, i didnt looked on the other snipets, but:

You need a db connection, i dont know if this happens in the db.php

mysql_query is deprecated, and is completely removed in PHP7.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage.php:30 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage.php on line 30

Answer (score 0):

`mysql()` - The old mysql_* functions deprecated in PHP 5.5. In this short tutorial you will get a instruction how to solve this error message.

**Why was mysql deprecated in PHP 5.5?**

Because the below listed are missing points in PHP 5.5

- Stored Procedures
- Prepared Statements
- (SSL-)Encryption
- Compression
- Full charset support

**How to solve the warnings?**

Currently mostly many MySQL connections in PHP use this construct:

**Replace:**

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db('dbname', $link);
?>
```

**With**

The way with MySQLi would be like this:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
```

**Filthy and fastest solution:**

Suppress all deprecated warnings including them from mysql_*:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

## Solution for your problem

**Deprecated features in PHP 5.5.x**

> The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the **MYSQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.**

replace all `mysql_` functions into `mysqli_*` functions

> You have to make concatenation of the PHP variables in order to print it. Since then alone it will display the data.

**Replace:**

```
print '<a href="systemlogin2.php">$row['company_name']</h2>';
print '<p><img border="0" src="$row['company_logo']" width="230" height="198"></p>';
```

**With:**

```
print '<a href="systemlogin2.php">'.$row['company_name'].'</h2>';
print '<p><img border="0" src="'.$row['company_logo'].'" width="230" height="198"></p>';
```